# What is my hard drive physical sector size? fdisk, smartctl etc.. give different answers

Tags: hard-disk, fdisk, smartctl, badblocks

The harddrive is connected with an external enclosure via USB3.0.

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST4000DM004-2CV104
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5425 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

- You can see that it shows `4096 bytes physical` in the above output.
- But all the following results show `512` bytes:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: USB3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
```

```
$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/hw_sector_size
512

$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/physical_block_size
512
```

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,PHY-SeC /dev/sdb
NAME   PHY-SEC
sdb        512
└─sdb1     512
```

```
$ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdb
512
```

So what is the real hard drive physical sector size?

I think it should be `4096`, but I don't know why all other commands give me wrong result.

- Btw, the reason why I want to find the real physical sector size is because I want to use `-b 4096` when running `badblocks`.

Thanks a lot.

- PS: If the answer is `4096`, are there any other tools in Linux can show the real result other than `smartctl`?

I found another command will show 4096:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep -i physical
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
```

Comment: Is the drive connected directly via SATA? Or is USB involved? I have got a USB adapter that makes `fdisk` and similar programs "think" the physical sector size is 512, even if it's 4096. It looks exactly like in your case. In my case `smartctl` is right. I have actually tried `badblocks -b 512` with a somewhat faulty disk of this type and errors came in 8-packs. This was how I learned the hard way my USB adapter plays tricks.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks a lot for your comment. You are in every stachexchange sites. :) Yeah, you are right. I am using an external enclosure via USB3.0. (I just updated the question about this info). If I can trust `smartctl` result, then I will use `badblocks -b 4096` then to make it run much faster.

Comment: Please note my comment is based solely on my experiences with *my* USB adapter. It's not an answer, YMMV. [Seagate should know](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/3-5-barracudaDS1900-14-2007US-en_US.pdf).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks a lot for the link. Then it's 4096 then based on seagate pdf doc. I think you can provide it as an answer. Basically, `smartctl` and `hdparm ` are more reliable than other commands.

Comment: To add more confusion, it's 4K physical emulated at 512-byte sectors ([512e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#512_emulation_(512e))),
from [here](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/barracuda-fam/barracuda-new/en-us/docs/100805918n.pdf).

Comment: I'm not going to answer because I believe a good answer should not be limited to your HDD model or brand. IMO "check the specs" would not be a good answer either. Specification is data, not explanation. I lack deeper understanding of the general problem. If anyone wants to use my comments in their answer, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to fdisk, its a USB disk - so information is hidden.

smartctl has a database of many disks, so it can get the physical size.

In fact, any HD built in the last few years, especially in the multi-TB sizes will have physical block sizes of 4096 bytes.

I've just been looking at my smallish NVME drive and gdisk says that logical/physical sizes are both 512 bytes - but partitions will be aligned on **2048 sector** boundaries (thats 1Mib). It says the same about SATA SSD's.